# Elixir - sum of list values with recursion

Tags: erlang, elixir

Just trying to do simple sum of list values.

```
defmodule Mth do 

    def sum_list([]) do 
        0
    end

    def sum_list([H|T]) do
        H + sum_list(T)
    end

end

IO.puts Mth.sum_list([1, 2, 300])
```

But I get this error:

```
**(FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Mth.sum_list/1
    pokus.ex:3: Mth.sum_list([1, 2, 300])
    pokus.ex:14: (file)
    (elixir) src/elixir_lexical.erl:17: :elixir_lexical.run/2
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:316: Code.require_file/2**
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use lowercase letters for variable and functions names. Identifiers starting with uppercase are reserved for modules:

```
defmodule Mth do 

  def sum_list([]) do 
    0
  end

  def sum_list([h|t]) do
    h + sum_list(t)
  end

end

iex> IO.puts Mth.sum_list([1, 2, 300])
303
:ok
```

Comment: It would be unwise to implement a sum_list function this way because you would not benefit from Elixir's tail call optimisation. `h + sum_list(t)` would be executed as follows

1. `sum_list(t)`
2. `h +`

So the last function call here would be the `+`. This would mean that if you had a very long list you could get a stack overflow error. Somewhat ironic, I know.

Answer (score 8):

To improve upon Chris's solution, if you want your sum function to be tail recursive, you'd need to modify it a bit to be:

```
defmodule Mth do 
  def sum_list(list), do: do_sum_list(list, 0)

  defp do_sum_list([], acc),    do: acc
  defp do_sum_list([h|t], acc), do: do_sum_list(t, acc + h)
end

iex> Mth.sum_list([1, 2, 300])
303
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use `Enum.reduce` you can go simpler:

```
defmodule Mth do
  def sum_list(list), do: Enum.reduce(list, 0, &(&1 + &2))
end
```

Comment: `def sum_list(list), do: Enum.reduce(list, 0, &Kernel.+/2)` this also works ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just for sake of completeness this would also work:

```
defmodule Mth do

  def sum_list(list), do: do_sum_list(list,0)

  defp do_sum_list(l,i_acc), do: Enum.reduce(l, i_acc, fn(x, accum) -> x + accum end)

end
```

I post this solely for reference for others who may find this question and it's answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sum_list=[1,2,300]     
Enum.sum sum_list     
303
```